# Problem opening different screen for the list of data items using jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn, navigation-compose

Clicking on item 1 opens Screen1,
Clicking on item 2 opens Screen1,
Clicking on item 3 opens Screen1,

Instead the folowing should happed:

Clicking on item 1 should open Screen1,
Clicking on item 2 should open Screen2,
Clicking on item 3 should open Screen3,

Where am i going wrong.

**Data Item:**
`data class DataItem(val text: String, val imageResId: Int)`

**List of data item:**
`val dataItems = listOf(     DataItem("Item 1", R.drawable.concrete),     DataItem("Item 2", R.drawable.plaster),     DataItem("Item 3", R.drawable.blocks) )`

**Screen 1**
`@Composable fun Screen1(navController: NavController, dataItem: DataItem) {     Column(         modifier = Modifier             .fillMaxSize()             .padding(16.dp),         horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,         verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center     ) {         Text(text = "Screen 1")         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))         Image(             painter = painterResource(id = dataItem.imageResId),             contentDescription = null,             modifier = Modifier                 .size(200.dp)                 .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)                 .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)         )         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))         Text(text = dataItem.text)     } }`

**Screen 2**
`@Composable fun Screen2(navController: NavController, dataItem: DataItem) {     Column(         modifier = Modifier             .fillMaxSize()             .padding(16.dp),         horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,         verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center     ) {         Text(text = "Screen 2")         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))         Image(             painter = painterResource(id = dataItem.imageResId),             contentDescription = null,             modifier = Modifier                 .size(200.dp)                 .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)                 .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)         )         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))         Text(text = dataItem.text)     } }`

**Screen 3**
`@Composable fun Screen3(navController: NavController, dataItem: DataItem) {     Column(         modifier = Modifier             .fillMaxSize()             .padding(16.dp),         horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,         verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center     ) {         Text(text = "Screen 3")         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))         Image(             painter = painterResource(id = dataItem.imageResId),             contentDescription = null,             modifier = Modifier                 .size(200.dp)                 .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)                 .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)         )         Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))         Text(text = dataItem.text)     } }`

**Data List Screen, This screen will be displayed on the main screen**
`@Composable fun DataList(navController: NavController) {     LazyColumn {         items(dataItems) { item ->             Box(                 modifier = Modifier                     .fillMaxWidth()                     .clickable {                         navController.navigate("screen1/${dataItems.indexOf(item)}")                     }             ) {                 Row(                     modifier = Modifier                         .fillMaxWidth()                         .padding(16.dp),                     verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically                 ) {                     Image(                         painter = painterResource(id = item.imageResId),                         contentDescription = null,                         modifier = Modifier                             .size(64.dp)                             .clip(shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium)                             .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)                     )                     Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))                     Text(text = item.text)                 }             }         }     } }`

`@Composable
fun MyApp() {
val navController = rememberNavController()

```
NavHost(navController, startDestination = "dataList") {
    composable("dataList") {
        DataList(navController = navController)
    }
    composable(
        route = "screen1/{index}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("index") { type = NavType.IntType })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val index = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("index")
        val dataItem = if (index != null && index < dataItems.size) dataItems[index] else dataItems[0]
        Screen1(navController = navController, dataItem = dataItem)
    }
    composable(
        route = "screen2/{index}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("index") { type = NavType.IntType })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val index = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("index")
        val dataItem = if (index != null && index < dataItems.size) dataItems[index] else dataItems[0]
        Screen2(navController = navController, dataItem = dataItem)
    }
    composable(
        route = "screen3/{index}",
        arguments = listOf(navArgument("index") { type = NavType.IntType })
    ) { backStackEntry ->
        val index = backStackEntry.arguments?.getInt("index")
        val dataItem = if (index != null && index < dataItems.size) dataItems[index] else dataItems[0]
        Screen3(navController = navController, dataItem = dataItem)
    }
}
```

}`

Each list item should open the screen corresponding to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Data List Screen u have the following line

```
navController.navigate("screen1/${dataItems.indexOf(item)}")
```

instead of hardcoded screen1 u should pass the index (or id) of the screen, like

```
navController.navigate("screen${index}/${dataItems.indexOf(item)}")
```

Comment: Thanks, Sergei Mikhailovskii, for the quickest reply, It Solved the problem, I was not passing the arguments properly, but not the code is running as desired.